# Montar menu dinâmico com PHP

Tags: php, menu, dropdown

Pessoal estou tentando montar dinamicamente um menu com submenus com dados vindos de uma tabela do banco de dados, porém não consegui chegar a um resultado que funcionasse.

Tenho esse código para criar o menu e submenu em outro site, porém a forma de criação do menu do outro site era diferente (apenas `ul` e `li` de forma mais simplificada) e não consegui adaptar para chegar no resultado espero (final da questão).

```
<?php
$items = array ( 1 => array ( 'parent' => '0', 'tit_pag' => 'Inicial', 'url_pag' => '/', 'target_url' => '_self', 'id' => '1', ), 2 => array ( 'parent' => '0', 'tit_pag' => 'Principal 1', 'url_pag' => '/', 'target_url' => '_self', 'id' => '2', 'child' => array ( 3 => array ( 'parent' => '2', 'tit_pag' => 'Item 1', 'url_pag' => 'link1.html', 'target_url' => '_self', 'id' => '3', ), 4 => array ( 'parent' => '2', 'tit_pag' => 'Item 2', 'url_pag' => 'link2.html', 'target_url' => '_self', 'id' => '4', ), 5 => array ( 'parent' => '2', 'tit_pag' => 'Item 3', 'url_pag' => 'link3.html', 'target_url' => '_self', 'id' => '5', ), ), ), 6 => array ( 'parent' => '0', 'tit_pag' => 'Principal 2', 'url_pag' => '#', 'target_url' => '_self', 'id' => '6', 'child' => array ( 7 => array ( 'parent' => '6', 'tit_pag' => 'Item 4', 'url_pag' => 'link4.html', 'target_url' => '_self', 'id' => '7', ), 8 => array ( 'parent' => '6', 'tit_pag' => 'Item 5', 'url_pag' => 'link5.html', 'target_url' => '_self', 'id' => '8', ), 9 => array ( 'parent' => '6', 'tit_pag' => 'Item 6', 'url_pag' => 'link6.html', 'target_url' => '_self', 'id' => '9', ), ), ), 10 => array ( 'parent' => '0', 'tit_pag' => 'Principal 3', 'url_pag' => 'link7.html', 'target_url' => '_self', 'id' => '10', ), 11 => array ( 'parent' => '0', 'tit_pag' => 'Principal 4', 'url_pag' => 'link8.html', 'target_url' => '_self', 'id' => '11', ), );

function get_menu($items) {
    $html = "<ul>";
    foreach($items as $key=>$value) {
        $html.= '<li><a href="/'.$value['url_pag'].'" target="'.$value['target_url'].'">'.$value['tit_pag'].'</a>';
        if(array_key_exists('child',$value)) {
            $html .= get_menu($value['child'],'child');
        }
            $html .= "</li>";
    }
    $html .= "</ul>";
    return $html;
}
print get_menu($items);
?>
```

O código acima gera o seguinte resultado:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="//" target="_self">Inicial</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="//" target="_self">Principal 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/link1.html" target="_self">Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="/link2.html" target="_self">Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="/link3.html" target="_self">Item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/#" target="_self">Principal 2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/link4.html" target="_self">Item 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="/link5.html" target="_self">Item 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="/link6.html" target="_self">Item 6</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/link7.html" target="_self">Principal 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="/link8.html" target="_self">Principal 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Porém o resultado que eu precisava era esse:**

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="//" target="_self">Inicial</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown submenu">
        <a href="//" target="_self" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Principal 1 <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="link1.html" target="_self">Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="link2.html" target="_self">Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="link3.html" target="_self">Item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown submenu">
        <a href="/#" target="_self" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Principal 2 <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="/link4.html" target="_self">Item 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="/link5.html" target="_self">Item 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="/link6.html" target="_self">Item 6</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/link7.html" target="_self">Principal 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="/link8.html" target="_self">Principal 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena entender [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e ler o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Comment: Seu menu é basicamente `<ul>` e `<li>`, não entendi qual foi a dificuldade. Qual foi o HTML gerado por esse código para os dados que apresentou? Qual é a diferença em relação ao HTML desejado?

Comment: Editei a questão, veja que o resultado que o PHP gera é diferente do resultado que eu precisava, porém não consegui editar o código para que eu conseguisse deixar igual.

Comment: @Woss mas a questão depende do resultado do banco que a cada inserção pode mudar o resultado dos itens. Como eu disse esse resultado é sim do php, pois uso em outro site e está funcionando e gera esse resultado. A variável `items` vai receber os dados do banco de dados

Comment: @Woss uma dúvida, está aparecendo pra vocês a imagem do print do banco de dados? Porque os dados de `items` estão na imagem

Comment: Dê um `var_dump($items)` antes de chamar a função e inclua o resultado disso na pergunta.

Comment: Coloquei o valor de `$items`no código pessoal e tirei a referencia ao banco, desculpe a minha ignorância

Comment: Editei a pergunta, deixando apenas a parte que interessa. Resultado que gera o PHP e resultado esperado!

Comment: Repare que nos seus dados nenhum item tem a chave child, então nunca entra no if dentro da função.

Comment: @bfavaretto o código retorna o resultado correto, o problema está em como adicionar as outras informações que eu preciso para que ele fique igual ao segundo código postado.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui chegar ao resultado que eu esperava criando uma nova função para gerar os submenus, desta forma ficou assim:

```
<?php
    $items = array ( 1 => array ( 'parent' => '0', 'tit_pag' => 'Inicial', 'url_pag' => '/', 'target_url' => '_self', 'id' => '1', ), 2 => array ( 'parent' => '0', 'tit_pag' => 'Principal 1', 'url_pag' => '/', 'target_url' => '_self', 'id' => '2', 'child' => array ( 3 => array ( 'parent' => '2', 'tit_pag' => 'Item 1', 'url_pag' => 'link1.html', 'target_url' => '_self', 'id' => '3', ), 4 => array ( 'parent' => '2', 'tit_pag' => 'Item 2', 'url_pag' => 'link2.html', 'target_url' => '_self', 'id' => '4', ), 5 => array ( 'parent' => '2', 'tit_pag' => 'Item 3', 'url_pag' => 'link3.html', 'target_url' => '_self', 'id' => '5', ), ), ), 6 => array ( 'parent' => '0', 'tit_pag' => 'Principal 2', 'url_pag' => '#', 'target_url' => '_self', 'id' => '6', 'child' => array ( 7 => array ( 'parent' => '6', 'tit_pag' => 'Item 4', 'url_pag' => 'link4.html', 'target_url' => '_self', 'id' => '7', ), 8 => array ( 'parent' => '6', 'tit_pag' => 'Item 5', 'url_pag' => 'link5.html', 'target_url' => '_self', 'id' => '8', ), 9 => array ( 'parent' => '6', 'tit_pag' => 'Item 6', 'url_pag' => 'link6.html', 'target_url' => '_self', 'id' => '9', ), ), ), 10 => array ( 'parent' => '0', 'tit_pag' => 'Principal 3', 'url_pag' => 'link7.html', 'target_url' => '_self', 'id' => '10', ), 11 => array ( 'parent' => '0', 'tit_pag' => 'Principal 4', 'url_pag' => 'link8.html', 'target_url' => '_self', 'id' => '11', ), );
    
    function get_submenu($items) {
        $html2 = '<ul class="dropdown-menu">';
        foreach($items as $key=>$value) {
            $html2.= '<li><a href="/'.$value['url_pag'].'" target="'.$value['target_url'].'">'.$value['tit_pag'].'</a>';
            if(array_key_exists('child',$value)) {
                $html2 .= get_submenu($value['child'],'child');
            }
                $html2 .= "</li>";
        }
        $html2 .= '</ul>';
        return $html2;
    }               
    
    function get_menu($items) {
        $html = '<ul class="nav navbar-nav">';
        foreach($items as $key=>$value) {
            if(array_key_exists('child',$value)) {
            $html.= '<li class="dropdown submenu"><a href="/'.$value['url_pag'].'" target="'.$value['target_url'].'" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">'.$value['tit_pag'].' <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>';
            }else{
            $html.= '<li><a href="/'.$value['url_pag'].'" target="'.$value['target_url'].'">'.$value['tit_pag'].'</a>';}
            if(array_key_exists('child',$value)) {
                $html .= get_submenu($value['child'],'child');
            }
                $html .= "</li>";
        }
        $html .= '</ul>';
        return $html;
    }
    print get_menu($items);
?>
```

**RESULTADO**

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="//" target="_self">Inicial</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown submenu">
        <a href="//" target="_self" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Principal 1 <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="/link1.html" target="_self">Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="/link2.html" target="_self">Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="/link3.html" target="_self">Item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown submenu">
        <a href="/#" target="_self" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Principal 2 <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="/link4.html" target="_self">Item 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="/link5.html" target="_self">Item 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="/link6.html" target="_self">Item 6</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/link7.html" target="_self">Principal 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="/link8.html" target="_self">Principal 4</a></li>
</ul>
```